# How to push values to Array as 2d array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to generate like [[1540906200000,53.33],[1540992600000,54.72],[1541079000000,55.56],[1541165400000,51.87],[1541428200000,50.4]]

For that I have the below code, but it is not working as I am getting error says Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in [null].

I have tried multiple ways no luck.

```
    var arrObject = new Array();
   $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                debugger;
                if (item.Dataset != '' && item.Dataset >= 0) {
                    var date = item.DateCreated.replace(/\//g, "").replace('Date', "").replace('(', "").replace(')', "");
                   arrObject[parseInt(date)].push ( parseFloat(item.Dataset))
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your question is related to the parsing data not using the Highcharts library.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an empty array of size 0, var arrObject = new Array(); , Therefore if you try to access any index say x, arrObject[x] , it will return undefined. So the code will parse like
undefined.push(parseFloat(item.Dataset)) which is throwing an error

Comment: I am getting same error event after declaring the array size  
        var arrObject = new Array(50);

Comment: I managed it in different way  like below     
                  var dcVoltageData = data.DCVoltage.map(function (o, i) {
                    return [parseInt(o.DateCreated.replace(/\//g, "").replace('Date', 
          "").replace('(', "").replace(')', "")), parseFloat(o.Dataset)];
                });